# PHP multiple replacements

Tags: php, replace

I have got multidimensional array (name + image path), where some names are similar, like:

```
array("name" => "OpenGL", "img" => "OpenGL.png"),
array("name" => "OpenGL Lighting ( Advanced )", "img" => "OpenGL-LightingAdvanced.png")
```

then I replace names with images.

```
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $ret=str_ireplace($extension['name'],'<img src="images/'.$extension['img'].'" alt="'.$extension['name'].'" />: ',$ret);
}
```

It works as long as array is sorted from shortest name to longest one, but in that case, longer names will never be changed, eg. OpenGL Lighting ( Advanced ) will be

```
<img src="images/OpenGL.png" alt="OpenGL" /></div>:  Lighting ( Advanced )
```

When I sort it from longes name to shortest one it is even worse, couse it will change name in src:

```
<img src="images/<img src="images/OpenGL.png" alt="OpenGL" />: -LightingAdvanced.png" alt="<img src="images/OpenGL.png" alt="OpenGL" />:  Lighting ( Advanced )" />:
```

My only idea is to check if there isn't *src="images/* or *alt="* before name, if so - replace, but I have no idea how can I easily do.

Comment: You could always just add the quotes to the replace, delimiting it!

Comment: Something like `str_ireplace($extension['name']." "`? Sadly I can't do so :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) will work:

```
foreach ( $extensions as $extension ) {
    $ret = sprintf( '<img src="images/%s" alt="%s" />: ', htmlspecialchars( $extension['img'] ), htmlspecialchars( $extension['name'] ) );
}
```

Comment: You'll need `htmlspecialchars()` for the string arguments to ensure correct html output...

Comment: 100% true, post updated to `htmlspecialchars( $extension['img'] )`

Comment: Maybe nooby, but I don't see how I can quickly use sprintf. $ret contains string like `"bla bla OpenGL bla bla OpenGL Lighting ( Advanced ) bla"` and I want to change that names into images...

Answer (score 0):

Somebody mentioned **`strtr()`**.

Very helpful but case-sensetive and I need case-insensitive function.
Luckily somebody wrote case-insensitive function **`stritr()`** in the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#82051).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the foreach loop around `str_ireplace()`, just use it like this:

```
$ret=str_ireplace($array_of_all_search_words, $array_of_all_replacement_words, $ret);
```

and it won't replace anything it has already replaced. You might still have to sort the search words by length, though.